# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: spring, servlets, struts

This the file web.xml in WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>glpi.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

         <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924761/no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-contextloaderlistener-registered)

Answer (score 22):

I think you are missing the context loader listener(to pick your spring context file(s)).

Add this to your web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You could also check out the **Initial web configuration** section @ http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html

Comment: thank you, but when i add the context loader listener , The module : HELPDESKGESTION\nbproject\build-impl.xml:719: has not been deployed.

Comment: tough to comment on that, without knowing what all is going on. But what am sure about is that your question relevant here should be solved by the above snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

You have both ContextLoaderServlet and DispatcherServlet set to load-on-startup = 1. That means either one of them could start first, and you need the ContextLoaderServlet to start first, since that's what creates the root WebApplicationContext that your error says is missing. So leave ContextLoaderServlet's load-on-startup at 1, and change the DispatcherServlet's to 2 or higher.

Actually, it's preferred to use [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#web-integration-common) instead of the Servlet unless you're on a really old container where the Listener doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 11):

Add following code in web.xml file, bcs it looks for contex to load so we have to declare it initially.

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently stumbled upon the same issue, and I knew for sure it couldn't be caused by misconfiguration because I've copied the entire *working* Tomcat installation from another machine. Yet I kept getting the same exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

As I've eventually figured out, it was a wrong JVM version that broke the application: this one used **Java 7**, whereas the working instance (and the webapp) was on **Java 8**.

Hope it helps someone struggling with this counter-intuitive error message.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by `this one` and by `the working instance` ?

Comment: `This one` refers to the instance giving the error, `working instance` is the source on another machine I copied the whole thing from (which was working fine).