# No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, dispatcher

I'm trying to create a simple Spring 3 application and have the following files. Please tell me the reason for this error

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Index Page<br/>
        <form:form commandName="loginBean" method="POST" action="login">
            <form:input path="userName" id="userName"/><br/>
            <form:input path="password" id="password"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>   
        </form:form>
        <a href="register.jsp">Go to Registration Page</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 
    <bean name="/login" class="com.infy.controller.LoginController"/>   
</beans>
```

This is the LoginController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginAction(@ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginBean bean){
        return new ModelAndView("success", "success", "Successful Login");
    }
}
```

And finally my LoginBean

```
public class LoginBean {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You'll have to have a ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml - It loads your configuration files.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You need to understand the difference between Web application context and root application context .

> In the web MVC framework, each DispatcherServlet has its own WebApplicationContext, which 
>   inherits all the beans already defined in the root WebApplicationContext. These inherited 
>   beans defined can be overridden in the servlet-specific scope, and new scope-specific 
>   beans can be defined local to a given servlet instance.

The dispatcher servlet's application context is a web application context which is only applicable for the Web classes . You cannot use these for your middle tier layers . These need a global app context using ContextLoaderListener .

Read the spring reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for spring mvc .

Comment: That'll need an applicationContext.xml and after that it gives a binding error

Comment: @Batman Also how are you auto detecting your controllers . You need an context:component scan or an '<mvc:annotation-driven />'

Comment: @Batman check the Spring reference I have put in . It'll help you .

Comment: I'm a newbie in MVC programming. I've just started to learn the model and the first framework I picked up is Spring. I think that there is some error in my config files as it is never able to reach the controller that means the bean is not initialized as part of the HTTPRequest. Please let me know how to configure them correctly, I think I'm missing something small.

Comment: Also, note that I'm _not_ _extending_ any controller, but only using annotations in my application. Controller is mapped only in the dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: @Batman you can found answer on your issue with `applicationContext.xml` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350721/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml

Comment: And also, listener should be declared in one line. Spaces, tabs and new lines cause applicationContext.xml loading problems.(in wildfly)

Answer (score 2):

And if you would like to use an existing context, rather than a new context which would be loaded from xml configuration by org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener, 
then see -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40694787/3004747

Comment: This can be used in addition to web.xml and also in absence of web.xml