# Spring - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error while trying to run a Spring project

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

Inspite of adding the listner on to my `web.xml`. I am still getting this error. Below is the listener I have added to my web.xml :

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWebRedirect-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param> 

 <listener>
 <listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 </listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Can someone help me out in this regard?

Comment: I think, there is probably another cause of getting Exception, you should take a look in the whole Exception trace, specially "caused by"

Comment: Moreover, I believe this causes problems when the <listener-class> is not defined in one line and spread across three lines..

Make it a point to declare these things without new line characters

Answer (score 17):

Hi @user2681868 I was also facing the same problem here are the steps you should follow.

1) in web.xml define this

```
<listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

2) create a applicationContext.xml in web-inf with this content

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    </beans>
```

Comment: Every answer I see, people mention ContextLoaderListener, but not the applicatoinContext.xml itself. And you were the first one. Thanks.

Comment: Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 126; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

I am getting the above error

Answer (score 4):

If you using Annotation:

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");



        ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(appContext);

        servletContext.addListener(contextLoaderListener);


        // Filter.
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Sorry but am I missing something?? Isn't this exactly what user2681868 also has in his web.xml!?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the first "/" in the

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      WEB-INF/HelloWebRedirect-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifiying contextConfigLocation try to specify dispatcher servlet

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>HelloWebRedirect</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

choose your servlet name according this template: /WEB-INF/${servlet-name}-servlet.xml

Comment: it doesn't make much difference I believe

Comment: It is possible to use Spring in a web application without using Spring-MVC. If the OP is not already using Spring-MVC I would not suggest he refactor his whole application in order to use it.