# Spring form submission using <form:form> tag

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

Whenever I use spring form tag(i.e. ) in login.jsp it shows me errors i.e. no Context Loader registered. I imported `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="HTTP://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` in my login.jsp page and tried everything in past 10 days. I want to use  tag in login form to print the validation errors but its not working. If I use simple html  then it works fine. I am attaching my eclipse console snapshot and snapshot of all codes. Kindly suggest me.

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIwve.jpg)

Comment: Can you please include the code and console output in your question rather than linking to an image?

Answer (score 0):

Please define ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml which loads your configuration files.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

see [No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924761/no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-contextloaderlistener-registered)