# Grails 2.3.11 with JDK 8 having an error in liberty server

Tags: java, grails, websphere-liberty

Currently I am working on Grails application and update the Grail version that compatible with JDK8. 
Configuration:
JDK 8u31
Grails 2.3.11
Maven 3.2.1
Liberty 17.0.0.2

My application is maven based. Everything is working fine on local, but when I deployed it in liberty server. I am getting below error.

> Error Page Exception com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [grailsWebRequest]: could not
>   be initialized    at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:4326)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:5058)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5038)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:528)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:315)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1025)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1043)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:632)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1777)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
>       Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [grailsWebRequest]: could not be initialized    at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:163)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:655)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:518)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:319)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:399)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:988)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1381)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:186)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:4281)
>     ... 23 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.initialize(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.initFilterBean(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:149)
>     ... 32 more

Please anyone have suggestion?

Comment: Quick google points at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924761/no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-contextloaderlistener-registered perhaps you need similar in a web.xml

Comment: I hope you have seen this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/28887888/1582629  Just double check the springloaded jars file sizes and make sure its same in both the places.