# SpringMVC Errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**CASE1:**
Iam getting below error :

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 14

11: <body>
12:     
13:     
14:      <form:form  method="get" commandName="user" action="login">
15:      
16:         <form:label path="Username" /><form:input path="uname"/>
17:         <form:label path="Password" /><form:input path="password"/>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:424)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:111)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:76)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

**WHEN IAM USING BELOW FORM:**

```
<form:form  method="post" commandName="user" action="login">

        <form:label path="Username" /><form:input path="uname"/>
        <form:label path="Password" /><form:input path="password"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form:form>
```

**CASE2:**
Iam getting 404 after when I SUBMITTED below form, I mean this url : `http://localhost:8443/BugTrackingSystem/login`

**WHEN IAM USING BELOW FORM:**

```
<form action="login" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname">
        Password: <input type="text" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**OTHER FILES:**
**LOGINCONTROLLER:**

```
package com.bts.controller;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

import com.bts.vo.User;

public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController{


     public LoginController(){
            setCommandClass(User.class);
            setCommandName("user");
        }



     protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object obj) throws ServletException {

         User user = (User) obj;
            System.out.println("username: "+user.getUname());


        return new ModelAndView("index","user", user);

     }


}
```

**WEB.XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>BugTrackingSystem</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

**USER.JAVA**

```
package com.bts.vo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

    public User() {

        countries = new ArrayList<String>();

        countries.add("India");
        countries.add("US");

    }

    private String uname;
    private String password;
    private List<String> countries;

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }
    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public List<String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
    public void setCountries(List<String> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

}
```

**DISPATCHER-SERVLET.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:order="1">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>     


</beans>
```

**CONTROLLERS-BEANS.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <bean name="login" class="com.bts.controller.LoginController">
        <property name="successView" value="index" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="productDetails"
        class="com.bts.controller.ProductDetailsController">
    </bean>



</beans>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <import resource="dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>
  <import resource="controllers-beans.xml"/>
  <import resource="datasource.xml"/>
  <import resource="hibernate-beans.xml"/>


</beans>
```

I am learning right now Spring, so I'm facing above problems, so please provide me a solution, I will use Annotations later after when I understood this issue..

Comment: remove the ´/´ in the bean names.

Comment: HI, I tried as you said, BUT still iam getting same errors, BTW I have updated above my stacktrace... pls chk it, if possible please run from your end..

Comment: Yeah, its not the only problem, I look into it.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014782/adding-context-loader-listener-to-web-xml-in-spring-mvc

Comment: you're saying me to remove '/' from this tag, right??? , HERE: <bean name="login" class="com.bts.controller.LoginController">
  <property name="successView" value="index" />
 </bean>   I did as you said, BUT still iam getting same errors as above....I tried using BOTH forms..  iam not understanding what still changes need to do, can u find any other errors in my xml files?

Comment: I seen your link, BUT i have "contextConfigLocation" inside <servlet>, instead of using <context-param>, so am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've edited your question to where it no longer reflects reality. You claim to receive an error that your code won't generate. If your original question is answered, you should accept the answer and ask another question if you have one.

Comment: too much problem, you better create different questions for differents problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following links:

http://duckranger.com/2012/04/spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

And this setup worked for me:

`web.xml`

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    [...]
</web-app>
```

`application-context.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <import resource="myOtherContext.xml"/>
</beans>
```

`myOtherContext.xml` (for the sake of having some import)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="login" class="test.LoginController"/>
</beans>
```

`dispatcher-context.xml` (Note that this is auto-addressed because my dispatcher servlet is called `dispatcher` and it appends `-context.xml` automatically)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">index</prop>
                <prop key="login.htm">login</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean name="index"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

`login.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form  method="post" commandName="user" action="login.htm">
        <form:label path="uname" /><form:input path="uname"/>
        <form:label path="password" /><form:input path="password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`LoginController.java`

```
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController {

    public LoginController() {
        setCommandClass(User.class);
        setCommandName("user");
    }

    @Override
    protected org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors, Map controlModel) throws Exception {

        return super.showForm(request, response, errors, controlModel);
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object obj) throws ServletException {

        User user = (User) obj;
        System.out.println("username: " + user.getUname());
        return new ModelAndView("index", "user", user);
    }
}
```

Comment: so, cant we use an application without using application-context.xml file? is it a MUST file?? BTW, i run with your above code and will let you know now..

Comment: BTW, should I neeed to use this?

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

in this link given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704286/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-contextloade

Comment: No, its not. You can use the import statements in every context.xml. It is convention to name the top level context.xml `application-context.xml` and work down from there.

Comment: @Irwin Please have a read of http://duckranger.com/2012/04/spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet/ to get to know what the DispatcherServlet does and how (etc.) I edited into my answer as well.

Comment: sure, i will definitely read that link, now iam having a doubt, should I use imports now, since iam using ContextLoaderListener, if u dont mind, can u just show me the code of yours application-context.xml and , web.xml file (full UPDATED code)

Comment: @Irwin I have not run your code, yet. I might if the suggestions I gave you don't yield the result. When I do, I'll give you the codes. But when you learn a new technique its important to work yourself into it.

Comment: atleast can u tell me , should I need to use import tags now, since iam using a Listeneer, right?

Comment: Yes. Use `<context-param>` and `import`

Comment: I just updated web.xml, application-context.xml, controllers-beans.xml files in my 1st post, now when I try to run using <form:form>, iam getting this exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30676/discussion-between-angelo-neuschitzer-and-irwin)

Comment: when iam using with  normal form tag, iam getting same 404 error for the url: http://localhost:8443/BugTrackingSystem/login (this url comes after when I submitted my form)

Comment: I tried with your updated code, BUT iam still getting same exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Comment: @Irwin Then, I'm sorry, I can't help you any further. This code of mine is a working example. It actually runs over here. So whatever you do, it must be something different then what I did. Please create a new Example Project and add exactly the code as I provided it and test it again.

Comment: HI, iam using now Annotations, iam getting same exception even using annotations also, can u please check my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777156/java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-f/16789190?noredirect=1#16789190